# toSearchableArray() send the same 1 row 7 times to Algolia?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, algolia, laravel-scout

This code retrieves one post from DB but sends it 7 times to Algolia ...

There are 7 items in the database

6 records with status = PUBLISHED

1 post with status = DRAFT

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $array = Post::where('status', '=', static::PUBLISHED)->toArray();
      return $array;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: This code, generate 5 Arrays, but now with the right data ?

$pst =  Post::select('id','title','excerpt','body')->where('status', '=', static::PUBLISHED)->get();

    return $pst->toArray();

Hmm, can anyone se my problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I found the answer to my big question. enum field "PUBLISHED" turned to true, anything else false, so Algolia could now easily figure it out :-)

This is the answer:

> $properties  = $this->toArray();
>   $properties['visible'] =
>   $this->status === 'PUBLISHED';
>
> return $properties;

:-) and goodnight

Answer (score 0):

`toSearchableArray` is called for each entry. If you don't want to index the model with status set to DRAFT, you can return an empty array.

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    if ($this->status === 'DRAFT') {
        return [];
    }

    return $this->toArray();
}
```